# Jenkins X: trying to execute 'jx boot' from a non requirements repo

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, continuous-integration, google-kubernetes-engine, jenkins-x

I'm trying to install Jenkins X on an existing Kubernetes cluster (GKE), using `jx boot`, but it always gives me the error `trying to execute 'jx boot' from a non requirements repo`

In fact, I have tried to use `jx install`, and it works, but this command is already marked as ***deprecated***, but I see it's still the method to use on Jenkins X's GitHub page.

Then another detail ... I'm in fact creating the cluster using Terraform because I don't like the idea that Jenkins X creates the cluster for me. And I want to use Terraform to install Jenkins X as well but that would be another question. :)

So how to install using `jx boot` and what is a `non requirements repo` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you trying to execute `jx boot` from within an existing git repository? Try changing into an empty, non-git directory run `jx boot` from there.

`jx` wants to clone the [jenkins-x-boot-config](https://github.com/jenkins-x/jenkins-x-boot-config) and create your dev repository. It cannot do so from within an existing repository.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've noticed is that running `jx boot` in an existing repo without a `jx-requirements.yml` it asks if you want to check out the Jenkins X boot config.

```
Creating boot config with defaults, as not in an existing boot directory with a git repository.
No Jenkins X pipeline file jenkins-x.yml or no jx boot requirements file jx-requirements.yml found. You are not running this command from inside a Jenkins X Boot git clone
To continue we will clone https://github.com/jenkins-x/jenkins-x-boot-config.git @ master to jenkins-x-boot-config
? Do you want to clone the Jenkins X Boot Git repository? [? for help] (Y/n)
```

I let it do this checkout, and then either let it crash or cancel it.
I can now go into the new repo, make changes to the `jx-requirements.yml` and run it as I want it to.